XFS corruption, superblock overwritten by plain file data (Debian 11/Kernel 5.10)
I encountered my first XFS corruption recently. It happened on 2 distinct VMs which were identically deployed (on GCE infrastructure), once on VM 'A' and twice on VM 'B'. A third identical VM 'C' seems to be OK, more on that below.
The fact that it happened on two distinct VMs in a short timeframe (3 corruptions in 10 days) tend to lower the probability of an infrastructure bug.
It also happened a few days after those VMs were upgraded from Debian 10/Kernel 4.19 to Debian 11/Kernel 5.10. It's thus quite possible that the bug appeared in (or was triggered by) this revision.
The corrupted VMs A and B are automatically shutdown every night (properly, via ACPI, I checked the logs), but VM C is running uninterrupted (and has not seen any corruption yet). It thus seems that the mount/umount cycles are helping the corruption bug to appear.
The XFS filesystem on those VM is a 1 TB one with 35M files and default settings (4KiB block, etc), here is the xfs_info output (yes, I don't use partition tables on non-root devices, it's much simpler this way) :
meta-data=/dev/sdb               isize=256    agcount=20, agsize=13107200 blks
         =                       sectsz=4096  attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0, sparse=0, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0    bigtime=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=262144000, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=0
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=25600, version=2
         =                       sectsz=4096  sunit=1 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0

The block device is a plain SCSI/paravirtualized disk, no LVM, no LUKS :
[    1.196188] scsi 0:0:2:0: Direct-Access     Google   PersistentDisk   1    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    1.234389] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] 2097152000 512-byte logical blocks: (1.07 TB/1000 GiB)
[    1.234391] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.234494] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.234496] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
[    1.234576] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.342761] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

The corruption manifests itself as :

a lost superblock : mounting is impossible, fs type not recognized
no superblock copy found: xfs_repair does not find any valid structure after 20min of scrubbing
dumping block #0 of the blockdevice shows ... the content of a PHP file ! (the fs is indeed hosting a large PHP app)

It really looks like someone did cat file.php >/dev/sdb, at least it's the same result.
I immediatly checked the ususal security thingies :

mode/owner/group of the blockdev are the usual root:disk
no user is in the disk group
sudo is not installed
su root is blocked via PAM
no dockerd
VMs are strictly up-to-date wrt. security patches (that's why they had to move do Debian 11 in June, Debian 10 LTS EoL), and seems they reboot every day they do run fresh kernels
they are not public-facing
no suspicious root/admin activity for VM 'A', none at all for VM 'B'

I'm quite baffled, has anybody encountered such a bug ? How is it possible that a file's data endup in the XFS superblock/block0 ?
